# Wordpress htaccess rewriterule for custom tab urls

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've done this a dozens times outside of wordpress but for some reason I can't get it to work in wordpress and not sure why. Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

The page `http://www.normalpl.com/digital/` has tabbed content, the tabs are books, movies, magazines, etc.

User visits url `http://www.normalpl.com/digital/movies/`

Display the `digital` page with the tabbed content, but instead of showing the default 1st tab, the movies tab is shown. The url stays the same in the browser but now wordpress sees `http://www.normalpl.com/digital/?tab=movies`. So on my `digital` page I can check what tab the user is trying to view and make that tab visible.

Here's an example of code that's not working on wordpress but I've used before on static sites. Perhaps this wouldn't work on a static site either, but I've done this before using a similar rewrite rule.

`RewriteRule ^digital/(movies)[/]?$ http://www.normalpl.com/digital/tab=$1 [L]`

Here's the whole htaccess block including wordpress (There are some WPSuperCache rules above this but don't think they have anything to do with my problem).

```
# BEGIN Digital Media Bucket URLS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^[/]?digital/([^/]+)[/]?$ http://www.normalpl.org/digital/?tab=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
# END Digital Media Bucket URLS

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What URL are you seeing? Is the RewriteRule not firing at all, or are you seeing something unexpected?

Comment: Not firing at all. I just get the wordpress 404 page.

Comment: Is `www.normalpl.org` the host name the request is going to? If so, the last RewriteRule will still rewrite everything to the `index.php` (in the second round of rewriting.)

Comment: www.noralpl.org is the domain for the site. But I would assume wordpress still needs to rewrite everything to index.php in order to load the correct wordpress page? I just want /digital/movies/ to load the /digital/ page without changing the url.

Comment: I updated my question to use the normalpl domain as that is the domain that I'm working on.

Comment: Try adding RewriteLogLevel to your httpd.conf file and see if the rule is even firing. It should give you some insight into what's going on.